# How do I get rid of these numbers

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

I need to replace the numbers with the words

sample output:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
```

input sample:

```
 15
```

This is my code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ int a;
int i = 1;

 

          scanf("%d",&a);
        
                      while(i<a){
     printf("%d\n", i);
      i+=1;
      if(i%3==0 && i%5==0){
                    printf("FizzBuzz");}
      else if(i%3==0){
            printf("Fizz");
      }
       
          else if(i%5==0){
            printf("Buzz");
                }
                      }
                return 0;
    }
```

This is the output of my code

```
1
2
Fizz3
4
Buzz5
Fizz6
7
8
Fizz9
Buzz10
11
Fizz12
13
14
FizzBuzz
```

Comment: It's not clear what the relationship between then input and output is. Giving an example is good but you also need to describe in words what the program requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You should

- Fix indentation of your code
- Stop printing the number unconditionally and have it print the number only if it don't print the words
- Have it add one to `i` only after all process is done
- Use `puts()` instead of `printf()` to have it print newline after the words
- Fix the loop condition
- Check if `fscanf()` succeeded

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int i = 1;

    /* check if reading succeeded */
    if(scanf("%d",&a)!=1){
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    while(i<=a){ /* fix the loop condition */
        /* no printing and adding before processing */
        if(i%3==0 && i%5==0){
            puts("FizzBuzz"); /* use puts */
        }
        else if(i%3==0){
            puts("Fizz"); /* use puts */
        }
        else if(i%5==0){
            puts("Buzz"); /* use puts */
        }
        else{
            /* print number only if the words are not printed */
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        /* add one to i only after processing done */
        i+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer of MikeCAT , you should first fix the identation. It's really confusing.
Now coming back to your question, you want to print words whenever the numbers are divisible by 3 and 5. You should not print the number each time at the starting of while loop. You should check condition and then print it. Answer to your question with printf will be :

```
include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int i = 1;

    
    scanf("%d",&a);

    while(i<=a)
    {                                          /* fix the loop condition */
    if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
    {
    printf("FizzBuzz\n"); 
    }
    else if(i%3==0)
    {
    printf("Fizz\n"); 
    }
    else if(i%5==0)
    {
    printf("Buzz\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
                         /* print number only now*/
    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
       /* add one to i*/
    i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```